# How to change UI language for midnight commander Mac

Tags: midnight-commander

i installed midnight commander by means of brew (brew install mc). But couldn't understand why it's in french. i've tried to reinstall it but it's turned out to be the same thing. Now i'm wondering how could i change the language to EN. Seems like there are no evident way to accomplish through GUI.

**P.S.
To let apply this alias persistently it's recommended to add this to .bashrc in other case the next time u start shell u have to type it again.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to make alias like:

```
alias mc='LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 mc'
```

On this way you will always run mc on English.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your zsh/ bash

Comment: Still there's no clear reason why MC uses other than English in my case. I noticed it happens whenever I have another language in Systems Preferences -> Language & Region -> Preferred languages, even if English is set to Primary.

Answer (score 0):

I've just removed the languages i dont want from the "locals" folder. But it is bad GUI design that it is not possible to force it to use whatever language you prefer from the applicaton settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).